# How to get same dns asnwer like 4.2.2.4

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

I've installed bind on my ubuntu 17.04 server and I configure like this : http://paste.ubuntu.com/25503024/

I want to when I run a query like `dig @mydns_IP www.google.com` it answers like when I ask from `4.2.2.4 or 8.8.8.8`. I have two server with two same configuration. But one of them answer the query differently. When I ask it about `google.com` it returns the correct IP address but authority section and additional section are empty like this one http://paste.ubuntu.com/25503022/ and If I change the `forward only` to `forward first` it returns list of root dns server in authority section for all queries.

How can I fix this ? I would like to answer be like this http://paste.ubuntu.com/25503028/.

Answer (score 0):

I delete all forwarders and make it a DNS cache only server by just adding `recursion on;` and at the moment it works fine.